# What's the difference between all the sins in vidui?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, viduy-confession

When saying ashamnu, bagadnu, gazalnu, etc, I'd like to have something specific in mind that feels relatable/relevant for each sin category. What's the difference between each of these sin categories and what's an example of each?

Comment: Try the Chaya Adam’s vidduy. Although not specific for the meaning of the words of vidduy, he says that all aveiros can and should be mentioned at the letter that they begin with. He gives tons of specific examples

Comment: It’s in chapter 143 of chaya adam. https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.143.1?lang=bi

Comment: Look at the back of the Artscroll machzor it has an individual explanation with examples for each one.

Comment: @Chatzkel are you aware of an English translation of that Chayei Adam?

Comment: @Shmuel https://www.panix.com/~jjbaker/vidui.htm

Comment: @Chatzkel much appreciated and great find!